# New Rubber Mat Stinks

Tags: rabbits, travel, cleaning, horses

I purchased a brand new rubber mat to use inside of a pet carrier.  The mat is easy to clean and provides a non-slip surface. But it stinks like new rubber.

I googled around and found several suggestions to soak in vinegar water for at least 30 minutes, I tried it and did not seem to make a difference.

Other suggestions are to leave it out in the sunlight. But winter is not the best time for that solution.

I have the mat sitting on a rack so it gets good air circulation. This should work but it could take weeks or months, so is about as effective as waiting for the summer sun.

How can I get the new rubber smell out of the rubber mat, in timely fashion, that will not harm the rubber or my pets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found to date, is hanging the mats out in the weather to maximize sun shine on them.  I turned them a couple times a week so the sun hit both sides.

I took a while.